# Can I see a specific device activity log (with dates) in a Huawei HG8247Q?

Tags: wireless-networking

Is it possible to see a activity history log of a specific device through admin access? The modem is a Huawei HG8247Q. Thank you.

Comment: But I can't find any activity log option in the admin menu...

Comment: @Akina: Please post a full answer.

Comment: @grawity I think it cannot be treated as an answer, nevertheless done.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I see a specific device activity log (with dates)

Identify records relative to this device by device's MAC-address (and then, maybe, by IP address assigned to it).

> But I can't find any activity log option in the admin menu...

There must be "View log" somewhere. Search it, set proper viewing level, then search for records you are interested in.

Comment: I don't want to know the navigation history of the specific device I just want to know the date and hour in which it was connected. I read in a forum that the web provider company has removed the event log view option from the admin menu for privacy reasons.

Comment: *I just want to know the date and hour in which it was connected.* If so it's enough to view DHCP lease log.

Comment: The helpdesk of the web provider inform me that it's only possible to see the devices that are or were connected to the network but without dates or time.

Comment: Log without timestamps??? Really?